# CURDATE() ADD INTERVAL on INSERT MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, time, timezone

What is the proper syntax for adding hours to `CURTIME()` in MySQL INSERT statment..

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `ordisp` (`date`, `time`, `operator`, `status`, `completed`, `name`, `email`) VALUES (CURDATE(), CURTIME(INTERVAL 2 HOUR), '".mysql_real_escape_string($operator)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($status)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($complete)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."')";
```

Thank you.

Comment: You could just go look at the mysql docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: your profile pic does look like you, dude.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

```
time(date_add(curdate(), interval 2 hour))
```

or just

```
time(curdate() + interval 2 hour)
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/6495)

BTW why not join the `date` and `time` columns into one `datetime` column?